# Get blog category and keywords using blog Id from query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am new to wordpress.Can any one help me how to get blog category and keywords of that blog with blog Id using  MySQL query.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I am trying to get the term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships , with that term_id wp_term_taxonomy and with term_id name and slug from wp_terms table . but seems that approach is incorrect.

Comment: please paste your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Initially I got confused about table structure

The query to get category is

```
 select name from wp_terms where term_id in(
select term_id from wp_term_taxonomy where term_taxonomy_id in(
 (select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships where object_id=YOUR_BLOG_ID)) and taxonomy='category');
```

and query for tags is

```
 select name from wp_terms where term_id in(
select term_id from wp_term_taxonomy where term_taxonomy_id in(
(select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships where object_id=YOUR_BLOG_ID)) and taxonomy='post_tag');
```